# neural network training stopping so soon

Tags: validation, neural-network, training-data

My feed forward neural network has 150 input neurons, 25 hidden neurons, and 3 output neurons. My training dataset has 43104 samples and my validation and testing datasets contain 9237 samples each. 
I am using validation check to stop training. the validation check is set to 6. However, my neural network stop training in 11 iterations! isnt that too early?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No its not too early. The training loop finishes based on an exit strategy. Its likely to be when the error on the validation set goes below a set threshold, although it can be set to various other parameters.
Once your network tests accurately on the test dataset, the number of  training iterations is not important.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at your goal value.
If there is huge gap, then you should increase the value of validation check.
Validation check can be increased by that function.

```
net.trainParam.max_fail = 8;
```

Here validation check is set to 8.